# How to simplify the It.IsAny<T>() parameters for setting up Mocks

Tags: c#, moq

In our unit tests we frequently use `Mock.Setup`. This leads to statements such as:

```
_mockedModel.Setup(x => x.Method1(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object>(),It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(1);
_mockedModel.Setup(x => x.Method2(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<object>())).Returns(1);
_mockedModel.Setup(x => x.Method3(It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(1);
_mockedModel.Setup(x => x.Method4(It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<object>(), It.IsAny<object>())).Returns(1);
```

This is quite verbose, and I would like to simplify the `It.IsAny<T>()` parameters.

We have tried doing the following:

```
Func<string> s = It.IsAny<string>;
Func<object> o = It.IsAny<object>;
_mockedModel.Setup(x => x.Method1(s(), o(), o())).Returns(1);
_mockedModel.Setup(x => x.Method2(s(), o(), o())).Returns(1);
_mockedModel.Setup(x => x.Method3(o(), o(), s())).Returns(1);
_mockedModel.Setup(x => x.Method4(o(), o(), o())).Returns(1);
```

But, although this does not give any errors, it does not Setup the Mock. E.g. Methods 1 to 4 return 0 and not 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Nkosi's answer helped me think up a solution. The solution is to place the It.IsAny() calls inside a property (or method):

```
private static string Str => It.IsAny<string>();
private static object Obj => It.IsAny<object>();
```

This allows the code to be written as follows:

```
_mockedModel.Setup(x => x.Method1(Str, Obj, Obj)).Returns(1);
_mockedModel.Setup(x => x.Method2(Str, Obj, Obj)).Returns(1);
_mockedModel.Setup(x => x.Method3(Obj, Obj, Str)).Returns(1);
_mockedModel.Setup(x => x.Method4(Obj, Obj, Obj)).Returns(1);
```

Comment: Yes it does, not sure I understand why 100%, thought that this would return the exact It.IsAny<T>() call that the Setup function requires.

Answer (score 3):

> But, although this does not give any errors, it does not Setup the Mock. E.g. Methods 1 to 4 return 0 and not 1.

That is because Moq `Setup` is explicitly looking for `It.IsAny<T>()` static method call within the expression in order to configure the setup correctly. That is by design.

By changing to the function in your attempt to simplify the expression, you force the expression to invoke the method call which returns the default of the generic type argument.

So your expression effective becomes

```
_mockedModel.Setup(x => x.Method1(null, null, null)).Returns(1);
//...
```

Comment: Any other way to achieve what I am trying to do that you are aware of?

Comment: None that I am aware of.